# Trying to render texture but I can't pass the variable to draw function

Tags: c++, oop, header-files, raylib

What I'm trying is basically loading a texture and then drawing it on the screen. I tried to do it with just one cpp file and it works just fine. But right now I have a structure like this:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "raylib.h"

class Player
{
public:
    Player(const char* texturePath);
    ~Player();
    void Draw();

private:
    Texture2D ShipTexture;
    Vector2 position;

    const char* texturePath;
};
#endif

#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(const char* texturePath)
{
    position = { 0, 0 }; 
    ShipTexture = LoadTexture(texturePath);
    if (ShipTexture.id == 0)
    {
        // Texture loading failed
        TraceLog(LOG_ERROR, "Failed to load texture from path: %s", texturePath);
    }
    else
    {
        TraceLog(LOG_INFO, "Texture loaded successfully from path: %s", texturePath);
    }
}

Player::~Player()
{
    UnloadTexture(ShipTexture);
}

void Player::Draw()
{
    if (ShipTexture.id != 0) 
    {
        DrawTexture(ShipTexture, position.x, position.y, WHITE);
    } 
    else 
    {
        TraceLog(LOG_WARNING, "Attempted to draw player texture before it was loaded!");
    }
}


#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "raylib.h"
#include "Player.h"

class Game
{
public:

    Game(const int screenWidth, const int screenHeight, const char* title);
    ~Game();

    // OTHER FUNCTIONS
private:
    // OTHER VARIABLES

    Player player;

};

#endif

#include "Game.h"

Game::Game(const int screenWidth, const int screenHeight, const char* title) 
        : screenWidth(screenWidth), screenHeight(screenHeight), title(title),
        player("texture/path/png")
{

}

void Game::Init()
{
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, title);
    SetTargetFPS(60);
}

void Game::Draw()
{
    BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        player.Draw();
    EndDrawing();
}

void Game::Loop()
{
    while(!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        Draw();
    }
}


#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    Game game(800, 600, "Space Invaders");

    game.Init();

    game.Loop();

    game.Shutdown();

    return 0;
    
}
```

When I compile and run this I get entire white screen(which is expected because of clearing the background) and I have a console output saying `"Attempted to draw player texture before it was loaded!"`. So it means loading the texture is succsessful but when it comes to the `Draw()` function function takes the default value as a texture which is null. IDK why it acts like that can someone explain please?

Comment: You didn't mention if you saw "Texture loaded successfully" in your log or not. According to this Reddit link [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/raylib/comments/vqfi4w/how_do_i_load_textures_using_raylib/) (I was looking it up for my own understanding of RayLib), loading the texture needs to come _after_ `InitWindow()` - but you're trying to do it in your `Game` constructor, _before_ you call `InitWindow()` via `Game`'s `Init()`... makes me suspect it is failing to load the texture.

Comment: @NickGris It makes sense I think this is the issue. But then what is the proper approach? How should I load my texture with using classes like this?

Comment: You could, for example, change `Player`'s texture loading to a public method (say, `LoadTextures()`), and then have `Game`'s `Init()` call `player.LoadTextures()` _after_ `InitWindow()`. Not too much of a shuffle.

Comment: @NickGris Oh sorry I missed the output because of raylibs default outputs I get this log when starting the exe:  `INFO: FILEIO: [path/to/png] File loaded successfully.
WARNING: IMAGE: Failed to load image data
ERROR: Failed to load texture from path: path/to/png ` first 2 lines are coming from default raylib and third one is coming from my debugging code why is that unsuccsesfull when the first line is saying file loaded succsessfully

Comment: It looks like it found the file OK, but didn't like the image data / encoding - maybe try another image temporarily? I've no idea if RayLib is fussy about encoding... or maybe it's something to do with the configuration of the surface (window) vs the encoding of the image.

Comment: Hmmm... according to [this](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/issues/3796) it might be that the PNG isn't really a PNG.